# How do I get hwid in linux operating system with python?

Tags: python, linux

How do I get hwid in linux operating system with python?

```py
subprocess.Popen('hal-get-property --udi /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer --key system.hardware.uuid'.split())
```

This is not working:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hal-get-property'
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working, can you post a stacktrace or the result of the code versus what you expect?

Comment: Note that `split()`ing a string is bad form -- you should really be specifying your argument set as a list. That wouldn't be related to the problem, though -- we need to know _how_ your program fails (exactly what exception is thrown) before we can start to speak to _why_ it fails. "Not working" is not a useful problem statement.

Comment: (`hal-get-property` isn't a standard tool all Linux distributions are obligated to provide, so when we don't know what assumptions are safe about distro / desktop environment / etc, we don't know if it's even installed; one of the many things showing a specific error would tell us is _whether the tool is even installed_).

Comment: (...there are plenty of other ways to get hardware identifiers, but most of them require root permissions; but you _also_ aren't telling us what permissions this code runs with, so we have no way of knowing which of those other ways could work)

Comment: ...another thing about your existing code: If the program you're running _does_ spit out the identifier you want when run under the account you already have access to on the distro you're running, the change needed may be as simple as telling your Python code to capture that program's stdout! That's a really easy fix, but because you aren't giving us any details we don't know if it's the specific fix you need.

Comment: raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hal-get-property' @C.Nivs

Comment: [Edit] details into the question, don't add them as comments, but that's not surprising. As I said, `hal-get-property` isn't a standard command Linux distros are required to provide.

Comment: That said -- it's _possible_ that `hal-get-property` is a real command on your distro, but you're on a platform where `subprocess` doesn't do an implicit PATH lookup. Can you run that same command successfully at a command line / in the terminal, or does it fail there too?

Comment: (...and you haven't answered the question I asked about what permissions your script runs with; if answers that need root work, that opens up a whole wealth of options).

Comment: There is no such command or anything. I guess this is outdated. Is there a new solution/command? @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
hw = subprocess.check_output(['cat', '/etc/machine-id'])
```

or `hw = subprocess.check_output(['sudo','cat','/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid']).decode().strip()`